# What is Median Error Distance and how to calucalte it

Tags: error, measurement-error

How to calculate **Median** Error Distance?

I'm looking at "Schulz A. et al. A Multi-Indicator Approach for Geolocalization of Tweets". They are calculating Median Error Distance. 
But how they are do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, the terminology used in the paper is slightly incorrect. What MED means is Median Euclidean Distance. What AED means is Average Euclidean Distance.

Euclidean distance is calculated by the formula in the following link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

MED is calculated by taking median of all the euclidean distances between the actual and predicted points